# Amazon S3: Cannot put object under a subdirectory

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Can you confirm me that with the following policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:CreateBucket",
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::viessmann"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:DeleteObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::viessmann/medias/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

It would allow me to write the following object in the given path:

`https://viessmann.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/medias/cache/brochure_thumbnail_medium/5abcf6b35e02b.jpg`

Right now, I'm getting an 403 Forbidden response.

Comment: Yes, the policy should allow it. How are you copying the file? Feel free to Edit your question to show more details.

Comment: Thanks. I just wanted to exclude any possible errors with the policy first before diggining any deeper with the library we're using.

Comment: You can test it by using the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) `aws s3 cp` command.